# Internals about Robot Movement

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As explained on **"http://learn.turtlebot.com/"** in the video about the teleoperation functionality ie. after running the command "roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch",
some questions arise that are as follows:

1. What does it actually do after taking the input from keyboard?
2. Is **turtlebot_teleop** an **ROS node** that **publishes** to some **"ROS Topic"** and we have a corresponding **"NODE"** implemented as a **subscriber** listening to that Topic?
   If so, are the components "ROS Topic" and "NODE" **already implemented** in ROS environment or Turtlebot Package?
   **If so, to which topic(name) *is the teleop node publishing and which node is listening to that topic**?*
3. Or does it directly control the robot movements?
   If so, what exactly is the information provided to robot for movements? **Are there any direct APIs for this**?
4. Can you provide some example source code to control the turtlebot movements?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209187/internals-about-robot-movement/) by [Kushal](https://answers.ros.org/users/22427/kushal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Kushal,

1. You are on the right track, turtlebot_teleop is a **ROS package** that contains a *launch file* called [keyboard_teleop.launch](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/indigo/turtlebot_teleop/launch/keyboard_teleop.launch). Said *launch file* invokes a **ROS node** called *turtlebot_teleop_keyboard* that takes the input from the keyboard and outputs [geometry/Twist](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) messages to the **topic** *cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop*. Those *Twist* messages contain the *linear* and *angular* speed that the robot should follow. Then there is another *node* that subscribes to the same *topic* and actually moves the robot. The *listening node* is actually a **nodelet** that depends on the underlying hardware of your turtlebot.
2. I can not think of a simple example right now, but you can check out the [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2015-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kushal](https://answers.ros.org/users/22427/kushal/) on 2015-05-15**:
Hi Martin,
Thank you very much for the response. Your answer provides the information required and will be helpful in progressing further.
Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [mahantesh_kothiwale](https://answers.ros.org/users/22428/mahantesh_kothiwale/) on 2015-05-18**:
Dear Martin, Thanks!, even I was looking for these answers. I just started to learn ROS last week. I have questions: *cmd_vel_mux*  a default topic available ? what is name of listening nodelet, which actually moves the robot, is available by default in Turtle-Bot environment? or need to implement?